# How can I implement this design Charts Radius Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, package

I can't find any package to implement this UI

This is my design using Syncfusion_fluter

[image]

Comment: Share what UI you want to implement

Comment: you can use syncfusion package and you can try this package also https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Comment: @MunsifAli thanks any way but this package don't have conner radius

Comment: @Prashant please click enter image description here to see my UI that I want to design

Comment: what do you mean by conner radius

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.